# html tags in a string

Tags: php, html, tags

I need a php code where force users to add `<b>` tag before all `<i>` tags in a textarea if detected.

Here I have a html example:

```
<i>HyperText Markup Language</i> (HTML) is the main markup language for creating <i class="i-text">web pages</i> and other information that can be displayed in a <i>web browser</i>.
```

And want them to add like this:

```
<b><i>HyperText Markup Language</i></b> (HTML) is the main markup language for creating <b><i class="i-text">web pages</i></b> and other information that can be displayed in a <b><i>web browser</i></b>.
```

Thank you

Comment: If you know you want bold tags before each italic tag, just check and add them yourself if they are missing. Don't force the user to add them if it is your wish, not the user's, to display the text also in bold. Forcing the user's hand because of a design decision you made is a bad practice!

Comment: You would need to use javascript to make the changes as a user enters text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm confused as to why you'd need to do this. If you want the `<i>` tags to be bold, you can simply change the styling on that tag where your result is displayed in CSS:

```css
i {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

For instance, if your result was displayed something like:

```html
<div id="result">
    <i>HyperText Markup Language</i> (HTML) is the main markup language for creating <i class="i-text">web pages</i> and other information that can be displayed in a <i>web browser</i>.
</div>
```

You'd use:

```css
div#result > i {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/JbFsx/).

Comment: It's not what the author want, by I agree with this response... Also, you should use `<em>` instead of `<i>` (and `<strong>` instead of `<b>`) if you're using xHTML/HTML5

Comment: @MaximeLorant `<b>` and `<i>` aren't deprecated. That would entirely depend on what type of information is being conveyed. http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html

Comment: My bad, its use is 'discouraged', not deprecated indeed :) Cf: http://xhtml.com/en/xhtml/reference/b/

Answer (score 1):

as you write your tags like this. why not you can define that tag in the CSS. in this Form

```
i{ 
font-weight:bold
}
```

. as per this any where you need to  tag that elememt also look asper italic or bold.

Answer (score 0):

If you´ll be forced to add b tag for any porpuse and dont works for u code only use css, can use preg_replace and a simple Regular expressions:

```
$texto =  $_REQUEST['texto']; //text sending by form
echo  preg_replace(  array("/<i>/","/<\/i>/"), array( "<b><i>","</i></b>"), $texto );
//or u cant assing to a var
```